# Do I have to duplicate the Virtualhost directives for port 80 and 443?

Tags: apache, virtualhost

I have a long and intricate list of <VirtualHost> directives, and I have to duplicate them into separate <VirtualHost> groups for ports 80 and 443 because I'm using SSL. Whenever I update my mod_rewrite rules I have to remember to do it in both places or else I'll break my app... this duplication is asking for trouble. Is there a way to combine or alias these -- the only difference between the two is that the port 443 version contains the SSLEngine, SSLCertificateFile and the like.

My <Virtualhost> contains many mod_rewrite rules, LocationMatch rules, CGI directives, etc.

Also, I can't use .htaccess files.

Comment: A duplicate of http://serverfault.com/questions/83669/apache2-with-ssl-do-i-have-to-copy-virtualhost-blocks

Answer (score 53, accepted):

Can't you use an include directive to include the common rules. [here](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/core.html#include)

[article](http://blog.techstacks.com/2008/01/production-use-for-include-directive.html)

eg.:

```
<VirtualHost _default_:80>
    ...
    include conf/common_rule.conf
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost _default_:*>
    ...
    include conf/common_rule.conf
</VirtualHost> 

<VirtualHost _default_:443>
    ... #SSL rules
    include conf/common_rule.conf
</VirtualHost>
```

Comment: thanks for this; btw, [here's an updated version](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/core.html#include) of the apache `include` directive, which is the first linked-to resource in your answer

Comment: A simpler solution for me was to rename *:80 to *:443 and then setup a very tiny *:80 VirtualHost that redirects. I realize this doesn't directly answer the original question, but if there's interest I'm happy to share my config.

Answer (score 36):

You can use any # of hosts and ports in a single Virtualhost directive.

```
<VirtualHost addr[:port] [addr[:port]] ...> ... </VirtualHost>
```

In My case I used.

```
<VirtualHost *:80 *:443>
  ServerName loop.lk

 ....
SSLEngine on
SSLCertificateFile /etc/apache2/ssl/local.crt

</VirtualHost>
```

Comment: SSLEngine on seems to be applied even when the site is accessed via http, resulting in an error page.

Comment: If you have a `<VirtualHost *:80 *:443>` block, I'm assuming you can then have a separate block for `<VirtualHost *:443>` that only includes the SSL stuff.  Is that correct?

Comment: @iconoclast No you can't have another <VirtualHost > directive. You can use <If "%{SERVER_PROTOCOL} != 'HTTPS'">
 ....
</If> OR <If "%{SERVER_PORT} != '443'">
 ...
</If>

Comment: @SampathPerera it does return an error message for me too: "Bad Request

Your browser sent a request that this server could not understand.
Reason: You're speaking plain HTTP to an SSL-enabled server port.
Instead use the HTTPS scheme to access this URL, please."

Comment: ..and it does in fact use HTTPS on both 80 and 443 ports, which can be proven by using URL like https://yourhost.yourdomain.com:80 in your browser.

Comment: Can you share more of your config, @SampathPerera? How did you make it work?

Comment: I think the <If></If> syntax would only work with Apache >=2.4.

Comment: Hi @GregDubicki , here is a complete example:
<VirtualHost *:80 *:443>
 ServerName loop.lk
 DocumentRoot /var/www/loop/web  
<Directory /var/www/loop/web>
  Order allow,deny
  Allow from All
  AllowOverride None
</Directory>
     SSLEngine on
     SSLCertificateFile /etc/apache2/ssl/apache.crt
     SSLCertificateKeyFile /etc/apache2/ssl/apache.key
</VirtualHost>

Comment: Thanks @SampathPerera, and what Apache HTTPD version are you using?

Comment: As noted above, `SSLEngine On` won't work, but most SSL settings are inherited from global config. You can put `SSLEngine optional` if you need per-vhost different settings of the key/certificate pair, for example. Also, in my experience, this needs the `_default_:443` Vhost as the first in the config, and that needs an explicit `SSLEngine on`.

Answer (score 10):

Sorry to bump up an old post like this, but in order to help other Googlers out there I wanted to share how I dealt with it:

I have a couple of vhosts on my localhost, say: `localhost`, `foo.com`, `bar.com`

This being a localhost site on my laptop (macosx) I could get away with self-signed certificates and thus the ssl-part is the same for all the vhosts...

What I did is this:

I created the directory `/etc/apache2/extra/vhosts/`.

I created a `/etc/apache2/extra/vhosts/localhost.conf`:

```
ServerName localhost
DocumentRoot "/www/localhost"
<Directory /www/localhost>
  Require all granted
</Directory>
ErrorLog "/var/log/apache2/localhost.error_log"
CustomLog "/var/log/apache2/localhost.access_log" common
```

A `/etc/apache2/extra/vhosts/foo.conf`:

```
ServerName foo.com
DocumentRoot "/www/foo.com"
<Directory /www/foo.com>
  Require all granted
</Directory>
ErrorLog "/var/log/apache2/foo.com.error_log"
CustomLog "/var/log/apache2/foo.com.access_log" common
```

A `/etc/apache2/extra/vhosts/bar.conf`:

```
ServerName bar.com
DocumentRoot "/www/bar.com"
<Directory /www/bar.com>
  Require all granted
</Directory>
ErrorLog "/var/log/apache2/bar.com.error_log"
CustomLog "/var/log/apache2/bar.com.access_log" common
```

And finally a `/etc/apache2/extra/vhosts/ssl.conf`:

```
SSLEngine on
SSLCertificateFile "/etc/apache2/ssl/server.crt"
SSLCertificateKeyFile "/etc/apache2/ssl/server.key"
```

And in my `/etc/apache2/extra/httpd-vhosts.conf`:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
  Include /etc/apache2/extra/vhosts/localhost.conf
</VirtualHost>
<VirtualHost *:443>
  Include /etc/apache2/extra/vhosts/localhost.conf
  Include /etc/apache2/extra/vhosts/ssl.conf
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost *:80>
  Include /etc/apache2/extra/vhosts/foo.conf
</VirtualHost>
<VirtualHost *:443>
  Include /etc/apache2/extra/vhosts/foo.conf
  Include /etc/apache2/extra/vhosts/ssl.conf
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost *:80>
  Include /etc/apache2/extra/vhosts/bar.conf
</VirtualHost>
<VirtualHost *:443>
  Include /etc/apache2/extra/vhosts/bar.conf
  Include /etc/apache2/extra/vhosts/ssl.conf
</VirtualHost>
```

Comment: Also went with this solution. Works great

Comment: No need to apologize for "bumping". StackOverflow's point is to collect the best answers, not to be a chat room. The idea of needing to have a different thread based on time is a holdover from the days of dial-up Bulletin Board Systems.

Answer (score 7):

Another option instead of using `Include` is using `Macro` (so you can keep it all in one file).

First enable the macro module:

```
a2enmod macro
```

Then put your shared stuff in a macro and `use` it from your virtualhosts:

```
<Macro SharedStuff>
   ServerName example.com
   ServerAdmin example@example.com
   <DocumentRoot /var/www/example>
      ...
   </DocumentRoot>
</Macro>

<VirtualHost *:80>
  Use SharedStuff
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost *:443>
  Use SharedStuff

  SSLEngine On
  SSLProtocol All -SSLv2 -SSLv3
  ...
</VirtualHost>
```

Macros can also take parameters, and be defined in other files that are included; so you can use them a bit like Functions, and save a lot of duplication across your Apache config files.

See here for more details:

https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/mod_macro.html

Comment: Great answer, but this isn't in 2.2 in case anyone wanted to know.

Comment: No, this is a 2.4 onward feature; however, 2.2 went EOL with the final release in July 2017 so really everyone should be on 2.4 by now :)

Answer (score 2):

You could put the common configuration into a separate file and include it in both VirtualHost segments. For example:

```
<VirtualHost 192.168.1.2:80>
  Include conf/common.conf
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost 192.168.1.2:443>
  Include conf/common.conf
  (put your ssl specific cofiguration stuff here ...)
</VirtualHost>
```

Answer (score 0):

You could also specify the common directives within a  container instead of within the  itself. That's what I do, mostly because I prefer mod_rewrite rules at the directory level instead of at the server level, but it should work equally well for you too.

Comment: You're missing a critically important word.  Can you add that?  And if you could give an example that would also be helpful.