# apache virtualhost SSL + non-SSL

Tags: virtualhost, apache, httpd.conf

I'm having trouble figuring out what's the proper way to setup a SSL virtual host + a non-SSL copy of it.

I have it like this now:
`<VirtualHost myip:80>

plenty of directives here

</VirtualHost>`

and

`<VirtualHost myip:443>

same directives as above

</VirtualHost>`

And it works fine but every time I edit the directives in one of the vhosts, I must do it in the other as well. Anything cleaner and more elegant?

Comment: A duplicate of http://serverfault.com/questions/83669/apache2-with-ssl-do-i-have-to-copy-virtualhost-blocks and of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/679383/do-i-have-to-duplicate-the-virtualhost-directives-for-port-80-and-443

Answer (score 7, accepted):

To run a website on both HTTP and HTTPS URLs, your only option is to run 2 separate VirtualHosts with the same DocumentRoot.

If the directives context allows, you can keep some of the common settings in a .htaccess file in a folder that is parent to both DocumentRoots.

Comment: Thanks. I ended up using the Include directive inside VirtualHost and putting all common stuff in a separate file.